# Is there a better way to trim whitespace and other characters from a string?

Tags: c#, whitespace, trim

For example, if I want to remove whitespace *and* trailing commas from a string, I can do this:

```
String x = "abc,\n";
x.Trim().Trim(new char[] { ',' });
```

which outputs `abc` correctly. I could easily wrap this in an extension method, but I'm wondering if there is an in-built way of doing this with a single call to `Trim()` that I'm missing. I'm used to Python, where I could do this:

```
import string
x = "abc,\n"

x.strip(string.whitespace + ",")
```

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) states that all [Unicode whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode), with a few exceptions, are stripped (see **Notes to Callers** section), but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without manually defining a character array in an extension method.

Is there an in-built way to do this? The number of non-whitespace characters I want to strip may vary and won't necessarily include commas, and I want to remove all whitespace, not just `\n`.

Comment: The rub is forever in the "with a few exceptions" clause.  An api loses value when you need a Note to tell everybody why it might not work as expected.  Not the .NET way, you can certainly make it yours.

Comment: NB the double trim call fails in cases where you have whitespace **before** your last other unwanted character. Eg x = "abc ,\n".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regex makes this simple:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"^[\s,]+|[\s,]+$", "");
```

This will match Unicode whitespace characters as well.

Comment: I assume there are no unintended consequences with extending this, e.g. if I want to remove `,` and `b`, just using `@"^[\s,b]+|[\s,b]+$"`? Doing so works in a simple example, but I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do this:

```
x.Trim(new char[] { '\n', '\t', ' ', ',' });
```

Because newline is technically a character, you can add it to the array and avoid two calls to `Trim`.

**EDIT**

.NET 4.0 uses [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx) to determine if a character is considered whitespace. Earlier versions maintain an internal list of whitespace characters ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)).

If you really want to only use one `Trim` call, then your application could do the following:

1. On startup, scan [the range of Unicode whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode), calling `Char.IsWhiteSpace` on each character.
2. If the method call returns true, then push the character onto an array.
3. Add your custom characters to the array as well

Now you can use a single `Trim` call, by passing the array you constructed.

I'm guessing that `Char.IsWhiteSpace` depends on the current locale, so you'll have to pay careful attention to locale.

Comment: See the last paragraph of my question: "The number of non-whitespace characters I want to strip may vary and won't necessarily include commas, and I want to remove **all** whitespace, not just `\n`." I know I can just manually specify the characters, but if I want to remove *all* whitespace, the only way I know without manually defining a `char[]` is by calling `.Trim()` and *then* calling `.Trim(new char[] { ... })`

Comment: Try my edit. Just define whitespace characters in the array, along with your custom characters.

Comment: Just define an array that includes [all of these whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode)? Is there no better way? Is there no way to get a list or character array of all the characters .NET considers whitespace?

Comment: Unless you are creating an internationalized application, the three whitespace characters above are probably enough - might want to include `\r` as well. If you do need to worry about all Unicode whitespace characters, then you'll either have to include all of them in the array, or call `Trim` twice. Personally, I'd create the extension method that you suggested.

Comment: My application is internationalized and often uses input and output with numerous Unicode characters, which is why I was hoping for a general solution to strip all whitespace. If I have to call `Trim()` twice, though, it isn't really a problem. I just wanted to make sure there was not a better way first.

Comment: Mmk, that's the original documentation I was looking at (I think your Source link is the same one that I included, so I'm happy to get verification on that). That looks like it's the simplest solution, although I'm surprised .NET doesn't include a method of fetching the defined whitespace characters. +1 once I have the chance to vote again tomorrow.

Comment: Linking to the source is more a courtesy for future visitors, especially since you gave the same link. Glad it's helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have following Strip Extension method

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static string Strip(this string str, char[] otherCharactersToRemove)
    {
        List<char> charactersToRemove = (from s in str
                              where char.IsWhiteSpace(s)
                              select s).ToList();
        charactersToRemove.AddRange(otherCharactersToRemove);
        string str2 = str.Trim(charactersToRemove.ToArray());
        return str2;
    }
}
```

And then you can call it like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "abc\n\t\r\n ,  asdfadf , \n \r \t";
            string str2 = str.Strip(new char[]{','});
        }
```

Out put would be:

```
str2 = "abc\n\t\r\n ,  asdfadf"
```

The Strip Extension method will first get all the WhiteSpace characters from the string in a list. Add other characters to remove in the list and then call trim on it.

Comment: If you use `params Char[] otherCharactersToRemove` you can just give them as arguments with commas, without needing to make a char array in the calling code every time ;)

Comment: @Nyerguds Though as the documentation for [params](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) indicates, it is possible to supply a variable number of arguments *or* a single array argument as long as the array type matches the parameter type of the method being called.

Comment: @DavidRR Exactly. which means using params means you can give an array, give the elements, or give nothing at all. Tons of flexibility. What exactly is your point?

Comment: @Nyerguds When you stated "without needing to make a char array in the calling code," it may not have been obvious to some readers that using a single character array argument is still *possible*.

Comment: @DavidRR A single character is just a 1-item list of items in that case, actually. It's not some special case. Inside the function it'll always be treated as an array anyway.

Comment: @Nyerguds I believe we agree but I think I need to rephrase: "...using a single argument that happens to be a character array is still *possible*."